# Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments - Why is helm failing?

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm

Helm is failing with

> Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

and I don' understand why.
I'd like to expand the variables passed to helm but I have no idea how because the gitlab-ci.yml calls a file I cannot see.

```
include:
  - project: nyp/pipelines/reusable-pipelines
    ref: main
    file: deploy_hook.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  CLUSTER_NAME: eks-yolo-test
  TAG: v1.0.1
  # Implicit: name is repo name
  # Implicit: namespace is word between deploy- and -dev|uat|prod in branch name
  # Implicit: env is repo dev|uat|prod in branch name
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your $HELM_RELEASE_NAME AND $CHART_NAME are set and not empty?

Comment: @Raghu That's the point, I cannot expand the variables thus I cannot see if they're empty or not. But this is exactly as all the other services we've done and it's the only one that has an error

Comment: Do you have access to "nyp/pipelines/reusable-pipelines/deploy_hook.gitlab-ci.yml"? You will need to find where the variables are defined. Either in the CI yaml or a project level variable etc. Without this information, there is nothing much anybody can help understand the cause. Based on the message it does seem that one or both the variables  $HELM_RELEASE_NAME AND $CHART_NAME are empty